# Create DCRM Online Worklfow through web application

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, workflow-activity

I want to create workflow in CRM 2015 Online through API or code. Please note I have my own Front end to do this.

I followed this 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg328515(v=crm.7).aspx which says you can create custom workflow activity in Online CRM but with Partial Trust,

My question is that

1. I have to create and update key file everytime I update the rule screen.

Note: To update rules screen, I have front end application which connects with DCRM Online through API calls

2. Now to publish workflow, it requires me to create a key and then register it

   Scenario 1: User creates a rule and Application creates the workflow

   Scenario 2: User modifies current rule and Application updates the workflow, but since this change requires me to update the KEY file and then register it. This becomes Manual step. I want to remove this manual step and atomize this, is this Possible?

   Let me know, if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is for a custom workflow activity, which is not a workflow, but a custom step within a workflow.

The workflow itself uses Windows Workflow foundation.

Comment: Hi @jordi,
Thanks for your reply.

Yes, the link is for custom workflow activity, but that is the help I did get from google.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh913611(v=crm.8).aspx
This link clearly says that "The following sample shows how to programmatically create an asynchronous workflow in code instead of using a workflow editor or designer. This sample works only with an on-premises deployment of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 
** because custom XAML workflows are not supported in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online** ".

So if you are aware of any workaround, please share.

Comment: In an online environment you have to gro through the Sandbox environment so... I'm afraid you can't in Online.